# How to Solve Connection Problem Sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

i am new at sequelize orm , and i am using mysql database
and try to connection with my database but i don't get any connection or any error
could someone can figerout whats goes wrong with my code
this is the sequelize documention link
https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/getting-started/

```
import {Sequelize} from 'sequelize';


const dbConfig={
        "dbName":"mydb",
        "dbUser":"root",
        "bdHost":"localhost",
        "dbPassword":"Dell@8054",
        "dbPort":"3306",
        "dialect":"mysql"
        };


const sequelize = new Sequelize(dbConfig.db, dbConfig.dbUser, dbConfig.dbPassword, {
    host: dbConfig.bdHost,
    dialect: dbConfig.dialect,
    port:3306
  });
 
 sequelize
  .authenticate().then(con=>{console.log("con",con)}).catch(err=>{console.log("err",err)})
```

Output of console is  -- con undefined

i am expecting to get reponse if connection successfull or any error

Comment: i just use dbHost for storing hostname, it can be any name as you want

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
sequelize
.authenticate()
.then(() => {
   logger.info('MySQL connection has been established successfully.')  
})  
.catch(err => {
   logger.error('Unable to connect to the database:', err);
   process.exit(2)  
})
```